# Couldn’t sign you in This browser or app may not be secure

Tags: google-drive-api

We are working on a desktop product that supposes able to login into google drive.
This desktop application has been approved by google OAUTH.

Some of the accounts working fine,
but some of the accounts having issues follows:

> Couldn’t sign you in
> This browser or app may not be secure.
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

We tried the settings online, but none of them work.

I tried the ClientID of another application (Acrobat Reader DC).  I replaced the ClientID of Acrobat with my application, but I can log in normally. Excuse me, is there any difference in the ClientID configuration applied by Acrobat? How should I configure my ClientID.

Comment: Welcome to stack pease read [ask] edit your question and include [example]  what does acrobat reader have to do with authorization in a web browser?

Comment: Acrobat Reader also has the same function, but he can log in to GoogleDrive normally. After the comparison, only the clientID is inconsistent. So whether it is Adobe's ClientID that has made a special configuration.

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic] questions about applications are off topic here SO is a programming related forum.